# pylint W0622 (Redefining built-in) when overriding "standard" methods in subclasses

Tags: python, coding-style, warnings, pylint, software-quality

In Python, many methods define argument variables with "standardized" names, like:

```
def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
```

In the line above, variable **type** causes pylint to warn (W0622) that a built-in is being redefined: *Redefining built-in 'type' (redefined-builtin)*.

There are many ways to fix this and make pylint happy (rename the variable, add a pylint directive (**# pylint: disable=W0622**) to ignore the problem, etc.).

What is the best/preferred/suggested/conventionally-used way (if any) to maintain a good code quality and make pylint happy in these cases?

Answer (score 3):

It could be considered as a bad practise to disable pylint warning.

Quoting [quantifiedcode.com](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/exit_must_accept_three_arguments.html) :

> In order for `__exit__` to work properly it must have exactly three arguments: exception_type, exception_value, and traceback. The formal argument names in the method definition do not need to correspond directly to these names, but they must appear in this order.

As such a good option could be to use tuple packing `def __exit__(self, *exc)`

This what is suggested in this official documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html

Comment: If I do this as is suggested, pylint gives a warning: "Parameters differ from overridden '__exit__' method". So this is just replacing one pylint warning with another.